# Angular2: Send more than one event from child to parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Im sending one event like this for delete

```
<child-component *ngFor = "#todo of array" [taskobject] = "todo" 
(childevent) = "deleteparent($event)">Loading...</child-component>
```

how can i send another event along with childevent, is it comma seprated? like this?

```
<child-component *ngFor = "#todo of array" [taskobject] = "todo" 
(childevent) = "deleteparent($event)", 
(updateevent)> = "(updateparent)"Loading...</child-component>
```

also for edit/update request what http should i request to server, is it http.put also at server side, is it server.put('url')?

Update:

```
<child-component *ngFor = "#todo of array" 
[taskobject] = "todo"   (childevent) = "deleteparent($event)"
; (updatevent) = "updateparent($event)">Loading...</child-component>
```

Comment: Several expressions separated by semi-colon `;` should work. No idea what you mean by `htt.put` or `server.put('url')`.

Comment: its for example, http.delete at client side, and server.get() at server side, im making todo app

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Comment: Do you want to edit and delete ngFor row data by server???

Comment: Are `childevent` and `updateevent` two separate events defined on the child component?  If so, use `(childevent)="..." (updateevent)="..."`.

Comment: I practised for edit and delete queries they are working fine soon implement, I have succesfuly implemented delete from server to client, that was made possible by sending first data from child to parent from there to server, now i want to do exactly for edit, sending event from child to parent then parent to server, but as you will read my question, im only alowed to send only event for delete,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to handle multiple events on the same element.  If so, list the event handlers separated by space, just as you would with regular HTML attributes:

```
<child-component *ngFor = "#todo of array" [taskobject] = "todo" 
   (childevent) = "deleteparent($event)" 
   (updateevent) = "updateparent($event)">Loading...</child-component>
```

Comment: What about http request and server side for edit? is it http.put() and at server side express-server.put() ?

Comment: @blackHawk that depends on what is implemented on server, but the good practice is to use HTTP methods for what they were designed to do:
GET - get resource
POST - create new resource
PUT - update resource
DELETE - delete resource
there are some other methods, but these four are most commonly used

Answer (score 0):

Please try instead

```
(childevent)="deleteparent($event);updateparent($event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate them with `;` but condition is If first expression goes wrong, it would not evaluate the next expression. but here in your case both are functions so it would run as expected:

```
(anyevent)="function1($event);function2($event);etc"
```

this is also work with `&&` symbol like this:

```
(anyevent)="function1($event)&&function2($event);etc"
```

try it.hope this may help you.